# React Router v6 unable to render data using the new method of useLoaderData

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, json-server

I'm following a tutorial on youtube: [React Router v6 tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T8ZhepmbP4s&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9iVKmtNuCeIswnQ97in2GGf&index=7) that has a github repo associated with it: [iamshaunjp github repo](https://github.com/iamshaunjp/react-router-in-depth) and I'm stuck on lesson 7.  I will post to his github asking my question but I would also benefit from any of you good folks kind enough to help :)

I should say that I'm using the same structure of his repo but as I followed the tutorial (stuck at lesson 7) I've changed the purpose of the app from loading careers to loading baseball cards from my own db.json file.  I've changed my file names accordingly and everything was working until he/I created the Careers.js/BaseSet.js and CareerDetails.js/CardDetails.js files that utilize the `useLoaderData` and `useParams` hooks from `react-router-dom v6.8.0`.  In my BaseSet.js component I'm able to follow his use of the `route-parameter` data-structure to render a mapped group of Links each containing a different baseball player name from my db.json file vis a vis `json-router`.  The next step in the user-flow is for the user to click on one of these player-links and then my CardDetails.js component would render the full set of player-data from my db.json file using the same `routing-parameter` concept, however, I'm unable to do so.  I was very careful to read over each step leading up to this point but I'm unable to find a solution.  I've included my package.json file, index.js, App.js, LayoutNavigation.js and (I suspect the problem lies with) my BaseSet.js, CardDetails.js and my db.json file.  Thank you to anyone kind enough to read my problem.  I'll be sure to post my answer if I can solve it myself or if iamshaunjp helps.

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "scryball",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "json-server": "^0.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^6.9.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.8.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-table": "^7.8.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.6",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

index.js:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import './index.css'
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

App.js:

```
import React from "react";
import GlobalStyle from "./styles/GlobalStyle";
import {
  Route,
  createBrowserRouter,
  createRoutesFromElements,
  RouterProvider,
} from "react-router-dom";

//pages
import { Home } from "./pages/Home";
import { About } from "./pages/About";
import { Browse } from "./pages/Browse";
import Faq from "./components/Faq";
import Contact from "./components/Contact";
import { NoMatch } from "./pages/NoMatch";
import BaseSet, { baseSetLoader } from "./pages/BaseSet";
import CardDetails, { cardDetailsLoader } from "./pages/CardDetails";

//layouts
import { LayoutNavigation } from "./components/LayoutNavigation";
import HelpLayout from "./components/HelpLayout";
import BaseSetLayout from "./components/BaseSetLayout";

const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route path="/" element={<LayoutNavigation />}>
      <Route index element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="about" element={<About />} />
      <Route path="browse" element={<Browse />} />

      <Route path="help" element={<HelpLayout />}>
        <Route path="faq" element={<Faq />} />
        <Route path="contact" element={<Contact />} />
      </Route>

      <Route path="baseset" element={<BaseSetLayout />}>
        <Route index element={<BaseSet />} loader={baseSetLoader} />

        <Route
          path=":pathid"
          element={<CardDetails />}
          loader={() => cardDetailsLoader}
        />
      </Route>

      <Route path="*" element={<NoMatch />} />
    </Route>
  )
);

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <GlobalStyle />
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </>
  );
}
```

LayoutNavigation.js:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { Outlet, NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import styled, { createGlobalStyle } from "styled-components";

export const LayoutNavigation = () => {
  const [openDrawer, toggleDrawer] = useState(false);
  const drawerRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    /* Close the drawer when the user clicks outside of it */
    const closeDrawer = (event) => {
      if (drawerRef.current && drawerRef.current.contains(event.target)) {
        return;
      }

      toggleDrawer(false);
    };

    document.addEventListener("mousedown", closeDrawer);
    return () => document.removeEventListener("mousedown", closeDrawer);
  }, []);

  return (
    <Styles.Wrapper>
      <Navbar.Wrapper>
        <Navbar.Logo>ScryBall</Navbar.Logo>

        <HamburgerButton.Wrapper onClick={() => toggleDrawer(true)}>
          <HamburgerButton.Lines />
        </HamburgerButton.Wrapper>

        <Navbar.Items ref={drawerRef} openDrawer={openDrawer}>
          <Navbar.Item>
            <NavLink to="/">Home</NavLink>
          </Navbar.Item>
          <Navbar.Item>
            <NavLink to="/about">About</NavLink>
          </Navbar.Item>
          <Navbar.Item>
            <NavLink to="/browse">Browse</NavLink>
          </Navbar.Item>
          <Navbar.Item>
            <NavLink to="/baseset">2022 Topps Series 1 Baseball Base Set</NavLink>
          </Navbar.Item>
          <Navbar.Item>
            <NavLink to="/help">Help</NavLink>
          </Navbar.Item>
        </Navbar.Items>
      </Navbar.Wrapper>

      <main>
        <Outlet />
      </main>
    </Styles.Wrapper>
  );
};

const Styles = {
  Wrapper: styled.header`
    /* display: flex;
      background-color: #eeeeee;
      height: 100vh; */
  `,
};

const Navbar = {
  Wrapper: styled.nav`
    flex: 1;
    align-self: flex-start;
    padding: 1rem 3rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: white;
    @media only screen and (max-width: 40rem) {
      position: fixed;
      width: 100vw;
      bottom: 0;
    }
  `,
  Logo: styled.h1`
    border: 1px solid gray;
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  `,
  Items: styled.ul`
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    @media only screen and (max-width: 40em) {
      position: fixed;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      height: 100%;
      flex-direction: column;
      background-color: white;
      padding: 1rem 2rem;
      transition: 0.2s ease-out;
      transform: ${({ openDrawer }) =>
        openDrawer ? `translateX(0)` : `translateX(100%)`};
    }
  `,
  Item: styled.li`
    padding: 0 1rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    @media only screen and (max-width: 40em) {
      padding: 1rem 0;
    }
  `,
};

const HamburgerButton = {
  Wrapper: styled.button`
    height: 3rem;
    width: 3rem;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 12px;
    display: none;
    @media only screen and (max-width: 40em) {
      display: block;
    }

    /* Remove default button styles */
    border: none;
    background: transparent;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    &:after {
      content: "";
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      height: 150%;
      width: 150%;
      top: -25%;
      left: -25%;
    }
  `,
  Lines: styled.div`
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -0.125em;

    &,
    &:after,
    &:before {
      /* Create lines */
      height: 2px;
      pointer-events: none;
      display: block;
      content: "";
      width: 100%;
      background-color: black;
      position: absolute;
    }

    &:after {
      /* Move bottom line below center line */
      top: -0.8rem;
    }

    &:before {
      /* Move top line on top of center line */
      top: 0.8rem;
    }
  `,
};

const CSSReset = createGlobalStyle`
    *,
    *::before, 
    *::after {
      margin: 0; 
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: inherit;
    }
  
    html {
      font-size: 62.5%; /*1rem = 10px*/
      box-sizing: border-box;      
    }  
  
    body {
      font-size: 1.4rem;
      font-family: sans-serif;
    }
  `;
```

BaseSet.js:

```
import { useLoaderData, Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default function BaseSet() {
  const baseset = useLoaderData();

  return (
    <div className="baseset">
      {baseset.map((card) => (
        <Link to={card.cardId} key={card.cardId}>
          <h3>Player Name: {card.playerName}</h3>
          <h4>Team Name: {card.teamName}</h4>
          <br />
        </Link>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

//base set loader function
export const baseSetLoader = async () => {
  const res = await fetch("http://localhost:4000/baseset");

  return res.json();
};
```

CardDetails.js:

```
import { useLoaderData, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import cardFrontPlacehold from "../images/card-front-placehold.svg";
import cardBackPlacehold from "../images/card-back-placehold.svg";
import StatsTable from "../components/StatsTable";

export default function CardDetails() {
  const { pathid } = useParams();
  const card = useLoaderData();

  return (
    <div className="cardDetails">
      <h3>Player Name: {card.playerName}</h3>
      <h3>Id: { pathid }</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>Team Name: {card.teamName}</li>
        <li>Index Number: {card.cardId}</li>
        <li>Card Type: {card.cardType}</li>
        <li>Stats:</li>
        <p>HT:X'Y"</p>
        <p>WT: xxx</p>
        <p>BATS: LEFT/RIGHT/BOTH</p>
        <p>THROWS: LEFT/RIGHT/BOTH</p>
        <p>SIGNED, TEAMNAME YEAR[as free agent]</p>
        <p>ACS: [FREE AGENT], MM-DD-YY</p>
        <p>BORN: MM-DD-YY, [CITY, COUNTRY]</p>
        <p>blurb text</p>
        <hr />
        <h3>MAJOR LEAGUE BATTING RECORD</h3>
        <h3>LEAGUE LEADER IN XXXXX</h3>
        <StatsTable />
        <br />
        <img src={cardFrontPlacehold} alt="placehold for front of card" />
        <img src={cardBackPlacehold} alt="placehold for back of card" />
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

//loader function
//the params property is provided by ReactRouter and allows us access to the path property associated with BaseSetDetails component which is a prop within the route in App.js.
//cardId is our route
export const cardDetailsLoader = async ({ params }) => {
  const { pathid } = params;

  const res = await fetch('http://localhost:4000/baseset/' + pathid);

  return res.json();
};
```

db.json:

```
{
    "baseset": [
        {
            "cardId": "1",
            "playerName": "Shohei Ohtani",
            "teamName": "Angels",
            "cardType": "standard"
        },
        {
            "cardId": "2",
            "playerName": "Craig Kimbrel",
            "teamName": "Chicago White Sox®",
            "cardType": "standard"
        },
        {
            "cardId": "3",
            "playerName": "Huascar Ynoa",
            "teamName": "Atlanta Braves™",
            "cardType": "standard"
        },
        {
            "cardId": "6",
            "playerName": "Jazz Chisholm Jr.",
            "teamName": "Miami Marlins®",
            "cardType": "Future Stars"
        },
        {
            "cardId": "12",
            "playerName": "Gavin Sheets",
            "teamName": "Chicago White Sox®",
            "cardType": "RC"
        },
        {
            "cardId": "24",
            "playerName": "Trevor Rogers",
            "teamName": "Miami Marlins®",
            "cardType": "Rookie Cup"
        },
        {
            "cardId": "48",
            "playerName": "Guerrero Jr./Perez/Ohtani",
            "teamName": "AL™ HR Leaders",
            "cardType": "League Leaders"
        },
        {
            "cardId": "98",
            "playerName": "Francisco Lindor",
            "teamName": "New York Mets®",
            "cardType": "Combo Card"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This looks to be an issue caused by a typo. `loader={() => cardDetailsLoader}` should be `loader={cardDetailsLoader}`. Voting to close as "unreproducible or was caused by typo".

Comment: That's a good catch but I don't think that was the issue.  I was trying other ways of including the cardDetailsLoader as a value to the 'loader' prop and I forgot to restore this one part to my original code which matched your suggested edit.  Since you read through the code was there anything else that stuck out as a possible cause?

Comment: Nothing else really. What debugging steps have you taken? Does `fetch('http://localhost:4000/baseset/' + pathid)` return the data you expect? What is the value of `res.json()` in the loader function? What is the value of `card` in `const card = useLoaderData();` in the component? Can you provide a bit more detail about what you are actually seeing in the app when it's running? Are there any errors in the console?